# Javascript Map Array Last Item

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this:

```
map = ranks.map((row, r) => (
  row.map((rank, i) => {
    return [element(r, i, state, rank, toggled, onClick)];
  })
));
```

It maps through a 2-dimentional array.
After each row, I'd like to insert `<div class="clearfix"></div>`.

I think, if I could somehow get the last index for each row, so I will be able to use it in the row map callback. Can someone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Try something like:

```js
row.map((rank, i, row) => {
  if (i + 1 === row.length) {
    // Last one.
  } else {
    // Not last one.
  }
})
```

**Old answer:**

```
const rowLen = row.length;
row.map((rank, i) => {
  if (rowLen === i + 1) {
    // last one
  } else {
    // not last one
  }
})
```

Answer (score 163):

As LeoYuan answered, this is the correct answer, but it can be a bit improved.
`map` accepts a function with a third parameter, which is the iterated array itself.

```
row.map((rank, i, arr) => {
    if (arr.length - 1 === i) {
        // last one
    } else {
        // not last one
    }
});
```

or in a bit shorter version, using an object destructuring (thanks [Jose](/questions/38176352/javascript-map-array-last-item/46514721#comment81717434_46514721) from the comments):

```
row.map((rank, i, {length}) => {
    if (length - 1 === i) {
        // last one
    } else {
        // not last one
    }
});
```

Using an `arr.length` instead of `row.length` is a better and correct approach for several reasons:

1. When you mix scopes, it may lead for an unexpected bugs, especially in a poorly written or poorly designed code. In general, it is always a good way to avoid mixing between scopes when possible.
2. When you like to provide an explicit array, it will work as well. E.g.

   ```
   [1,2,3,4].map((rank, i, arr) => {
       if (arr.length - 1 === i) {
           // last one
       } else {
           // not last one
       }
   });
   ```
3. If you like to move the callback outside of the `map` scope (mainly for a better performance), it will be wrong to use `row.length` as it is out of scope. E.g. in the OP case:

   ```
   const mapElement = (rowIndex, state, toggled, onClick) => {
       return (rank, i, arr) => {
           let lastIndex = arr.length - 1;
           return [element(rowIndex, i, state, rank, toggled, onClick, lastIndex)];
       };
   };

   map = ranks.map((row, r) => row.map(mapElement(r, state, toggled, onClick)));
   ```

Comment: Why do you add `arr` instead of using `row.length`?

Comment: @Sanderfish Three reasons: 1. In general, I don't like to mix scopes, this way it makes it cleaner solution, especially when this code is part of a huge application; 2. This solution also works for explicitly defined arrays, e.g. `[1,2,3].map((rank, i, arr) => { ... })`; 3. If for whatever reason (for instance in a loop) you decide to move the callback outside of the scope, doing `row.length` will simply not work. I will update my answer to make it clear.

Comment: You can also do `.map((rank, i, { length }) => { ... })`

Comment: Agree yours is better approach

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems this is also better approach for React JSX since you can't just declare a variable inline?

Answer (score 24):

**Fewer lines of code with the same results**

```
row.map((rank, i, {length}) => (

  //last element
  if(i + 1 === length){ 

  }
));
```

Comment: This is the best solution out there!

Comment: this works nicely when you're already piping that can change the size.

Answer (score 7):

A shorter method would be to use .map combined with ternary operator, like this.

```
const positions = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]

positions.map((x, index, array) => {
    index === array.length -1 
        ? console.log("this is the last item in the array")
         : console.log( x)
}
```

//////////// explanation

x ### returns the current element .map is looping through

index ### returns the index(location of item in an array) of the current element.

array ### return the same element we are looping through so if we use sth like this

```
 ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"].map...
```

we'll still get the array we're looping through

array.length - 1  ### gives us the length of the array and - 1 gives us the index of the last element in the array.

Comment: I really like the readability on that ternary!

Answer (score 4):

A slight improvement on the accepted answer:

```
const lastIndex = row.length - 1;
row.map((rank, i) => {
  if (i === lastIndex) {
    // last one
  } else {
    // not last one
  }
})
```

This removes the arithmetic from inside the loop.

Comment: This will not work if the array's length dynamically changes during the runtime (which happens in most of the cases). That is why you must check array's length each end every time. Note, that `row.length` doesn't degrade the performance, as it doesn't count the items every time you request it, but stores the length as a parameter in the `Array` instance.

Answer (score 2):

simplify answer above

```
const array = ['apple','orange','banana'];

array.map((element, index) => (index === array.length - 1) ? \`${element}.\` : \`${element},\`);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check last index with your array's length. here is a logic

```js
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 10 + 1)) + 10

console.log("your last index is dynamic, ehich is ",randomnumber-1);
let arry = [];
for (i=1;i<randomnumber;i++){
    arry.push(i)
}

    arry.map((data,index)=>{
          if(index == arry.length-1 ){
            console.log("last index data  ",data)
          }
          else{
          console.log("remain data ",data)
          
          }

    })

    console.log("your last index is dynamic, which is ",randomnumber-1);
```

this is also works in dynamic arry changes..
it is a too simple technique which i use .. :-)

Comment: i found this is an optimal solution. thank you buddy.

Answer (score 1):

```
const array = ['apple','orange','banana'];

array.map((element, index) => {
  //Last element
  if (index === array.length - 1) {
    return `${element}.`;
  }
  //Another elements
  return `${element}, `;
})}
```

Will return `apple, orange, banana.`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most concise way (although a little "dirty" – you can get some ESLint errors and TypeScript also might not be happy about that) to access the `length` property in `array.map()` is to pull it out (by destructuring) of the third callback argument (which is the array we are mapping over) and then assign a new property e. g. `lastIndex`, which value is being derived from that previously pulled out `length`:

```js
let list = ["Alice", "Bob", "Cedrick", "David", "Emily"]

let mapped = list.map((item, i, {length, lastIndex = length - 1}) => {
  return i === lastIndex ? "lastitem: " + item : item
})

console.log(mapped)
```