# Why I Can not push value to array outside of function?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function:

```
static async assign( assigned_data, assigned_by ) {
    return new Promise( async ( resolve, reject ) => {
        let orders = [];
        await assigned_data.map( async( data ) => {

            // find each order and update 
            await data.assigned.map( async( order_id ) => {
                await this.findByIdAndUpdate( order_id, {
                    $set: { 
                        current_assigned: { 
                            user: data._id,
                            assigned_by: assigned_by,
                        },
                        last_assigned_at: Date.now(),
                        last_assigned_by: assigned_by,
                    },
                    $addToSet: { 
                        assigned_history: { 
                            user: data._id,
                            assigned_by: assigned_by,
                        } 
                    },
                }, ( error, order ) => {
                    if ( error ) {
                        console.log( 'error', error );
                    }
                    console.log( 'order', order );
                    orders.push( order );
                } );
            } );
        } );
        resolve( orders );
    } );
}
```

Even console.log( 'order', order ); print out order, but I can not push it to orders array.

But orders array still empty when I use this function.

When I use setTimeout it return extractly what I want.

```
setTimeout(function() {
          resolve( orders );
        }, 1000);
```

I don't want to using setTimeout, because I don't known how much time to set (eg. 1000 ms in above code).

Please tell me what wrong with my code. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Don't, under any circumstances, make a promise constructor `async`.

Comment: i think `resolve(orders)` is executed before any data is pushed into orders array via `async` methods. Execute it after data is pushed. As, settimeout will take a time of 1000ms to execute and before this orders are pushed into the array.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar sorry so what I need to do for my code?

Comment: try @seunggabi solution as you have to resolve orders only when data is pushed into the array.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I have tried and still get empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the things complicated. Nesting async await is not a good idea, as it is difficult to debug.

There are several problems. Let's take a look on a working sample.

```js
async function assign(assigned_data) {
  let orders = [];
  orders = await Promise.all(assigned_data.map(async(data) => {
    // find each order and update 
    return await Promise.all(data.map(async(order_id) => {
      return await call();
    }))
  }));
  console.log(orders);
}

async function call() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('order');
      resolve('order');
    }, 2000);
  });
  return promise;
}

data = assign([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]
])
```

First of all, you need `Promise.all` to await the `Promise`**s** formed by `map`.

Second, your nesting job still contains another array (I assume, thus you use `map` again). So you still need another `Promise.all` inside the previous `Promise.all`. (Please don't do this again for even complicated structure)

Lastly, put the real worker outside your nesting async-await loop.

Comment: Tai Wow, thanks you, I have learned alot from your answer! This resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, just callback!
but, I don't test this. hm..

```
static async assign(assigned_data, assigned_by) {
    const orders = [];
    return new Promise( async ( resolve, reject ) => {
        assigned_data.map((data, index) => {
            data.assigned.map((order_id) => {
                this.findByIdAndUpdate(order_id, {
                    $set: {
                        current_assigned: {
                            user: data._id,
                            assigned_by: assigned_by,
                        },
                        last_assigned_at: Date.now(),
                        last_assigned_by: assigned_by,
                    },
                    $addToSet: {
                        assigned_history: {
                            user: data._id,
                            assigned_by: assigned_by,
                        }
                    },
                }, 
                (error, order) => {
                    error ? console.log('error', error) : console.log('order', order);
                    orders.push(order);

                    if(index === assigned_data.length-1) {
                        resolve(orders); // just callback
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Sorry I don't see loop..

You can this. [Javascript Map Array Last Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176352/javascript-map-array-last-item)

Comment: You mean move resolve inside a map function? so what will return with a loop?

Comment: sorry I don't see your code loop.... so I updated my comment, call resolve when last index

Comment: @Enesy I edited my comment.. remove async-await, just callback;