# NodeJS+Express call async method in loop

Tags: node.js, express, ethereum

I'm trying to create a web api function with NodeJS and Express, retrieving data from private ethereum blockchain.

The problem is that the method `mytoken.tokenOfOwnerByIndex...` is async method in loop but want to wait all results until done and let the function returns tokenIds as a result.

I tried to use async/await but don't know how to use them properly.

Here is the snippet of my current code:

```
app.get("/get", function(req, res, next){

  var Web3 = require('web3');
  var BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');

  Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.sendAsync = Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.send;
  var web3 = new Web3();
  web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

  var contract = require("truffle-contract");
  var contractJson = require("./build/contracts/MyToken.json");
  var MyToken = contract(contractJson);
  MyToken.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  var tokenIds = [];
  MyToken.deployed().then(function(mytoken) {
    var account0 = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    mytoken.balanceOf(accounts0).then(function(balance){
      var x = balance.toNumber();
      for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
        mytoken.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(account0,0).then(function(tokenId){
          var y = tokenId.toNumber();
          tokenIds.push(y);
        });
      }
      res.json(tokenIds);
    });
  });
});
```

Can anyone guide me or give me the clue?

Comment: I can't see the necessary of changing the function into async-await form. What's the error do you have? Or you want to await them all together by `Promise.all()`?

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: I think you get it. That's related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219013/why-i-can-not-push-value-to-array-outside-of-function/52220372#52220372 , I think I made a pretty easy example for complicated form of promise.all already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in such cases library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) is really helpful. When working with iterables and promises you can use Bluebird's `map()` method ([map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)).

Since you have a number here (`var x`) and not iterable you could do something like this

```
var Promise = require('bluebird);

var x = balance.toNumber();
var promises = []; 
for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
   promises.push(mytoken.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(account0,0));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
   //do something
});
```

You can refer to the Bluebird [docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) for more information

Comment: You even do not need Bluebird in this case. `Promise.all(...)` already a part of standart.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! and thanks guys for answering my question.